# Building a dynamic array jQuery

Tags: jquery

The question is as follows:
There is a table with dynamic add and delete rows. Each row has a field with a date. It is necessary to collect an array for further definition of the start and end date.
But the [splice](/questions/tagged/splice) function returns a deleted array from which the dates are selected. The question is actually - how to optimize functions so that for adding and deleting all happened in one enumeration. Perhaps I do not quite understand the functionality of [splice](/questions/tagged/splice). I will be grateful for any hints and ideas.

```
var arr = [];
    $("table#taskclientcontact").on(' change', ['.datetask'], () => adddatetask())
    function adddatetask() {
        $('table#taskclientcontact input.datetask').each(function (index, element) {
            if (arr !== element) {
                arr.push($(element).val());
            }
        })
        console.log(arr);
    }

    $("table#taskclientcontact ").on('click ', ['.remove'], () => datetaskremove());
    function datetaskremove() {
        $('table#taskclientcontact  input.datetask').each(function (index, element) {
            var myIndex = arr.indexOf($(element).val());
            if (myIndex !== -1) {
                arr.splice(myIndex, 1);
               }
            console.log(arr);

        })
    }
```

Comment: @Wimanicesir wrong `const arr = [1]; arr.splice(arr.length, 0, 2); console.log(arr);`

Comment: But then how to separate functions - when we add and when we delete?  The events are different and depend either on changing a field or clicking a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the array index use `jQuery::index()` of the target element's `<tr>`:

```js
const arr = [...$('table#taskclientcontact .datetask')].map(elem => $(elem).val());
const log = () => $log.textContent = JSON.stringify(arr);
log(arr);

$("table#taskclientcontact").on('change', '.datetask', function(){
   arr[$(this).parents('tr').index()] = $(this).val();
   log(arr);
});
$("table#taskclientcontact").on('click', '.remove', function(){
  arr.splice($(this).parents('tr').index(), 1);
  log(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="taskclientcontact">
<tr><td><input class="datetask" type="date"></td><td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="datetask" type="date"></td><td><button class="remove">Remove</button></td></tr>
</table>
<div id="$log"></div>
```

Comment: A different approach. Thank you for the idea. Deleting it doesn't work yet. Everything is fine on the test on the site though. I'm trying to understand the reason - the deletion was performed through the datetaskremove function.

Comment: The thing is that strings are added dynamically and this script needs to re-read the page after adding a string.

Comment: @Ing.VakulinOleg if you provide a working snippet like in my answer it would be more clear what you want to achieve...